# No puedo acceder a los datos de process.env en Next

Tags: nodejs, next.js

Tengo el archivo .env.local en la raíz del proyecto. Con la dirección a google sheets y el numero de celular para checkout a whatsapp.

```
API_URL=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/asdfadfasdf
NUMBER=1231234
```

Para la api de google sheets process.env funciona perfecto

```
export default {
  list: (): Promise<Product[]> => {
    return axios
      .get(`${process.env.API_URL}`, {
        responseType: "blob",
      })
      .then(
        (response) =>
          new Promise<Product[]>((resolve, reject) => {
            Papa.parse(response.data, {
              header: true,
              complete: (results) => {
                const products = results.data as Product[];
                return resolve(
                  products.map((product) => ({
                    ...product,
                    price: Number(product.price),
                  }))
                );
              },
              error: (error) => reject(error.message),
            });
          })
      );
  },
};
```

Sin embargo, al querer pasar el numero de whatsapp, no me estaría funcionando. Si hardcodeo el numero si funciona, pero no con variables de entorno.

```
const SendButton: React.FC<Props> = ({ text, totalPrice, totalItems }) => {
  return (
    <Flex
      alignItems="center"
      justifyContent="center"
      position="sticky"
      as={motion.div}
    >
      <Button
        isExternal
        as={Link}
        colorScheme="whatsapp"
        width="fit-content"
        href={`https://wa.me/${process.env.NUMBER}?text=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`}
        leftIcon={
          <Image src="https://icongr.am/fontawesome/whatsapp.svg?size=32&color=ffffff" alt='' />
        }
      >
        {totalItems} items ({totalPrice})
      </Button>
    </Flex>
  )
}
```

Sabrían por qué sucede esto? Soy nuevo y quizás me estoy pasando por alto algo

Actualización: Entiendo que necesito usar NEXT_PUBLIC para que me aparezca del lado del cliente, en este caso sí me dejaría usar el numero. Pero esto no traería problemas de seguridad? Al dejarla publica se podría exponer mi número en el código?

Comment: Creaste con el proyecto con npx create-react-app miAplicationReact ?

Comment: Un problema de seguridad en este contexto seria si dejas key's en tu código base o algún dato que abra una puerta hacia tu base de datos. Ese nro de celular se supone que tiene que estar expuesto para whatsapp/

Answer (score 0):

Cuando creas el proyecto con create-react-app necesitas agregar el prefijo **REACT_APP** sino react no lo leerá

Usalo de esta manera:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/asdfadfasdf
REACT_APP_NUMBER=1231234
```

Comment: En realidad estoy usando Next